# What does it means to have function calling procedure in place of initialization (for loop)?

Tags: c, function, for-loop

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int fun()

    {
        static int num=16;
        return num--;
    }
    void main()
    {
        for(fun();fun();fun())
            printf("%d\n", fun());
    
    }
```

Here what is meaning of         `for(fun();fun();fun())` ?

All I know about for loop is that `for(initialization;condition;change in variable )` and they(ini..,cond...,chang...) should contain (some variable with value, algebraic condition, ..).

Please correct me.

Comment: It simply means that `fun` is called in all tree parts of the for-statement

Comment: You can imagine that `for (A;B;C) {D}` expands into `A; while(B) {D; C;}`

Comment: ... and its return value is used in the 2nd of the 3 parts of the `for` statement.

Comment: `initialization`, `condition` and `change in variable` can be any expression including `fun()` (which is an expression). Of course nobody would write weird code like this in the real world. Did you run this code?

Comment: You nailed it: ___should___ _contain_

Comment: yes, it returns 14 11 8 5 2

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun()
    {
        static int num=16;
        return num--;
    }

    void main()
    {
      fun();
      while (fun())
      { 
        printf("%d\n", fun());
        fun();    
      }
    }
```

Is it clear now?